# How to use material index from Object Info node?

Tags: materials, node-editor

*Material Index*:

[image]

This socket just outputs index pass set by user, just like simple *Value* node.

At first I thought it can play a role with material override, to see passes of real materials. Unfortunately, it doesn't work that way, as it also overrides all passes.

So, what is usecase for it?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe a slightly obscure one.. I've used the Material Index for discriminating between materials hit by a forward-cast ray in OSL.

Examples [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/110078/35559) and [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/117085/35559)... it's one of the few attributes actually returned by a shader-cast ray, at the moment..

Comment: Quite a voodoo magic you have here...