# Make a group of vertices appear infront of another

Tags: modeling, materials

im working on a character model and i would like to have the eyes appear through the hair like in the reference image, but i havent been able to figure it out at all

the white of the eye is not a separate object or anything, its just concave, so it would have to be a vertex group(?) instead of showing two separate objects through

is it possible like this? im super lost so any help is appreciated

[image]

[image]

as shown, i want the eyes to appear in front of only the green parts, and no other part of the hair or model

Comment: Maybe you should do it in the Compositor, with a separate layer for the glasses and eyes?

Comment: I guess you're in EEVEE, so [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/117085/35559) probably wouldn't help.....